# CartesianChart element couldn't be displayed due to a missing assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

When using LiveCharts in a WPF application, I encountered an issue where the CartesianChart element couldn't be displayed due to a missing assembly.

I have included the following namespace in my XAML header:

```
xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;assembly=LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF"
```

And my XAML code for the chart is:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart
    Series="{Binding Series}" Margin="75,75,75,53">
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

In the corresponding C# backend code, I used these namespaces:

```
using LiveChartsCore;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView;
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.WPF;
```

Despite this setup, the chart is not displaying. This suggests a potential issue with the assembly references or the setup of LiveCharts in your project.

How can I solve the problem?